# Central limit theorem: negative moments

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, moment-generating-functions, uniform-integrability, convergence-distribution

Let $X_{1},\ldots,X_{N}$ be i.i.d. random variables with mean 0 and variance 1. For simplicity, assume that $X_{1}$ has all finite moments. Let
\begin{equation}
S_{N} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\,\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_{i}
\end{equation}
The CLT says that $S_{N}$ converges in distribution to a normal random variable $X \sim N(0,1)$ as $N \to \infty$. It is also known that the following integer moments converge: For all $q \in \mathbb{N}$ we have
\begin{equation}
\lim_{N \to \infty}\mathbb{E}(|S_{N}|^{2q}) = \mathbb{E}(|X|^{2q})
\end{equation}
My question is to what extent the above limit continues to be valid when $q$ is non-integer, especially when $q$ is slightly negative $-1/2 < q < 0$? Is there some uniform integrability that would prove this?

Comment: You might start by wondering whether $\mathbb{E}(|X|^{2q})$ is finite for negative $q$ if $X \sim N(0,1)$

Comment: I think it is provided -1/2 < q < 0 ?

Comment: I doubt it theoretically, and trying with $q=-0.4$ I do not see convergence empirically (there are occasionally very large values).

Comment: Doubt what? that $\mathbb{E}(|X|^{2q})$ is finite for -1/2 < q < 0 ?

Comment: Exactly that: if I take $\mathbb{E}(|X|^{-0.8})$ and simulate a very large number of times, I do not see it giving an obvious value.  No do I expect it to:  $|X|^{0.8}$ has a positive density near $0$ so its reciprocal would not have a positive expectation

Comment: I thought that $\mathbb{E}(|X|^{2q}) = c\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2q}e^{-x^{2}/2}dx$. Now split the integral on some small interval $x \in [0,\epsilon]$. The Gaussian PDF is bounded by 1, so it's just integrating $\int_{0}^{\epsilon}x^{2q}dx$ which is finite if and only if $q > -1/2$.

Comment: That is an interesting point

Comment: So my original question...?

Comment: If $S_N$ takes the value $0$ with positive probability (for example when $N$ is even and $X_i$ take the values $1$ and $-1$ with positive probability) then the expectation is infinite. Hence some further assumptions are needed.

Comment: Let's say the $X_{i}$ are continuous random variables with some well-defined continuous and bounded density function.